# Django формирование страницы с фильтрацией

Tags: python-3.x, веб-программирование, django

У меня имеется вопрос по созданию `views.py` файла в проекте:

У меня имеется страница `list.html`, где отображаются все мои посты на сайте(мини блог),и добавил поле рубрик к модели поста,и теперь хочу сделать фильтрацию по рубрикам на этой самой страинце.

Как выглядит код кнопок выбора рубрик на `list.html`:

```
<div class="holder_clicks">
             {% for object in object_list %}
             <div class="radio_clicks" href="{{ url('news:rubric',pk=object.pk) }}">
                 <div class="radio_zone">
                     <div class="radio_circle"></div>
                 </div>
                 {{ object.rubric.title }}
             </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="clear"></div>

         </div>
```

Cкрипт, обрабатывающий нажатие кнопки:

```
<script>
 $('.radio_clicks').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('active');
 });
```

Вот как выглядит строка в `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^rubric/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$',NewsRubricListView.as_view(), name='rubric'),
```

А вот сам класс `NewsRubricListView` в `views.py`:

```
class NewsRubricListView(NewsListView):
def get_queryset(self):
    qs_filter = {}
    if self.request.GET.get('rubric'):
        qs_filter['rubric__title'] = self.request.GET.get('rubric')
    elif self.rubric:
        qs_filter['rubric__title'] = self.rubric

    return Post.objects.prefetch_related('files').filter(**qs_filter)
```

В следствии выполнения этого фильтрация не выполняется,и у меня вопрос:почему?Я что-то еще должен написать в скрипте?

Фреймворк  :django, шаблонизатор : jinja2